# random slope in linear mixed model for longitudinal data in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I am currently doing analysis on a longitudinal data set in which participants were followed druing several years at 3 time points at best. Some data are missing because of multiple reasons.
So, I don’t necessarly have my observation variable at each time point for each participant. That means that I can have one participant with t1, t2, t3, another with t1, t2, another with t1,t3 and another with only t1 measure. Moreover, time points follow-up are not the same for each participant.
That’s why I calculated a new variable (I called it time in my example) which is the delay from t1 (first observation) to time point of interest in months (for example subject 1 will have t1=0, t2=18, t3=36 and subject 2: t1=0, t2=19)
Participants had also different degrees of cognitive health and were classify into different groups.

My main interest is to look at the longitudinal effect of time among groups. That’s why I am running a linear mixed model in R with lmerTest package using this formula:

`m <- lmer(data = data, obs ~ group*time + (age + gender + education) + (1|subject))`

where group is a 6-levels factor and time is a continuous variable which corresponds to time delay between baseline and each follow up.
Because I expect to see different baseline levels of my observation variable but also different responses to my main factor time I would like to add a random slope with `(1+time|subject)` but it seems I can’t because time is not a factor but a continuous variable. I could also use my time_point variable instead of time because this one is a 3 levels factor and use this formula:

`m <- lmer(data = data, obs ~ group*time_point + (age + gender + education) + (1+ time_point|subject))`

but I feel that’s not correct because levels of this factor does not represent the same thing across subjects.

I am a master student without lot of statistical knowledge and I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: `(1+time|subject) ` is the way to go if `time` is a continuous variable.

Comment: Thank you Stéphane. I think I probably don't have enough data for this equation because R show me this error 'Error: number of observations (=660) <= number of random effects (=664) for term (1 + time | subject); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable'. Do you know if there is any solution to solve this problem ?

Comment: Hmm, not sure to understand. I think you have to remove `(1|subject)` if you include `(1+time|subject)`. Did you try that?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I did : 'm <- lmer(data = data, obs ~ group*time + (age + gender + education) + (1+time|subject))', but it looks like R can't handle this, I believe that I don't have sufficient observations to support my model. Is it also correct to not include the random slope because I've read different point of view until now ?

Comment: It seems as if the way you coded your time variable is the problem. How many unique values of time do you have? `xtabs(~df$time)` or use dplyr's `n_distinct(df$time)`.

Comment: I have lots of different values for this variable, 127 to be precise. Lots of them are time = 0 months because it was the first visit for the participants